# How to convert SQL query Where Clause Condition into JSON Object?

Tags: mysql, sql, json

Please help me to convert SQL query Where Clause Condition into JSON Object?

Answer (score 2):

```
**Here is Solution:~**

<script>

function handle_space_of_string(query){
    start = false;
    t = false;
    target_str = "";
    for (var i =0; i < query.length; i++){
        if(query[i] == "'" || query[i] == '"'){
            if(t == false){
                t = true;
                start = true;
            }else{
                t = false;
                start = false;
                
            }
        }
        if (start == true){
            if (query[i] == ' '){
                target_str += '~~!~~';
            }else{
                target_str += query[i];
            }
        }else{

            target_str += query[i];
        }
    }
    return target_str;
}

function parser_string(str){
    if (isNaN(str)){
        temp_str = str;
        ret_str = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < temp_str.length; i++){
            if ((temp_str[i]) == '"' ||  temp_str[i] == "'" || temp_str[temp_str.length] == '"' ||  temp_str[temp_str.length] == "'"){
                continue;
            }
            if (temp_str[i] == ' '){
                ret_str += '~~!~~';
            }else{
                ret_str += temp_str[i];
            }
        }
            
        return ret_str.replaceAll("~~!~~", ' ');
    }else{
        return str;
    }
}

function get_operator(op){
        operators = {
            "=":"eq",
            "==":"de",
            "!=":"ne",
            "<":"lt",
            ">":"gt",
            "<=":"le",
            ">=":"ge",
            "in": "in",
            "notin": "ni",
            "=":"is" ,
            "is":"is" ,
            "isnot":"isn",
            "!=":"isn",
        }
        return operators[op]
    }
function query_to_json_object(query){
    query = handle_space_of_string(query)
    query_tmp = query.split(" ")
    query = []
    for( var j = 0; j < query_tmp.length; j++){
        if (query_tmp[j] != ""){
            query.push(query_tmp[j].toLowerCase())
        }
    }
    query = query.join(" ")
    query = query.replace("is not", "isnot")
    query = query.replace("not in", "notin")

    query = query.split(" ")
    query.push(query[3])

    filters = []
    temp = []
    k = 0
    for (var i = 0; i < query.length+1; i++){
        temp[k] = query[i]
        k++
        if (i == query.length){
            break;
        }
        if(query[i+1].toLowerCase() == "and"){

            filters.push(
                {
                    "column_hash": parser_string(temp[0]),
                    "operator": get_operator(temp[1]),
                    "value": parser_string(temp[2]),

                }
            )
            temp = []
            k = 0
            i = i + 1
        }
        else if((query[i+1]).toLowerCase() == "or"){
            filters.push(
                [
                    {
                        "column_hash": parser_string(temp[0]),
                        "operator": get_operator(temp[1]),
                        "value": parser_string(temp[2]),
                    }
                ]
            )
            temp = []
            k = 0
            i = i + 1
        }
        
    }
    return filters
}
query = `Col1 is  Not 10 and  Col2 <  'Time  of ' AND  Col3 <= 8 AnD Col3 <= "Time1  2of" aNd Col3 <= 9`

document.write(query_to_json_object(query))
console.log(query_to_json_object(query))
</script>
```